# Jmeter Script Recording Error: SEC_ERROR_BAD_SIGNATURE

Tags: jmeter, certificate

Using **Jmeter 5.4.1**

Using **Firefox 91.3.0esr**

Last week I could use Jmeter Script Recorder

Today I get the following message:`SEC_ERROR_BAD_SIGNATURE`

My Firefox Connection Settings:

Manual Proxy Configuration:

HTTP Proxy: `Localhost`
Port: `8080`

The only difference I see from last week and this week is the Jmeter Certificate:

Has my Jmeter Certificate expired?

If so how do I get a new one?

[image: JmeterCertSetting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your time zone, your certificate will be valid till 7 PM GMT.

If it has expired already you can just re-start [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and it will generate a new certificate.

If you don't want to re-generate the certificate each 7 days you can put the following line to *user.properties* file:

```
proxy.cert.validity=365
```

it will configure JMeter to generate certificates valid for 1 year. More information: [Test Script Recorder certificate configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert)

With regards to your problem most probably you visited the website without proxy and not Firefox sees that the certificate chain has changed and doesn't allow you to browse to avoid potential [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack. Most probably you can get rid of this error if you [clear your browsing data](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox)

Also be aware that you can also record a JMeter test using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies, certificates, etc.